# Limitations of Kafka as a Distributed DB

Tags: apache-kafka

I have an application which requires an interesting orchestration between states of instances distributed across geographic regions, in combination with the need for a scalable distributed database.

At the moment I think that Kafka with log compaction will fit my needs for state maintenance and message exchange between instances, and Cassandra will fit my needs for high volume distributed reads and writes of persisted data.

However, there is quite a lot of data duplicated that way: Many of the data exchanged via Kafka would also need to be stored to Cassandra for distributed data access. Using Kafka for both messaging and distributed data querying and persistence seems tempting.

Therefore, I'm interested to figure out the real-world pros and cons to be expected when using e.g. the pull queries feature of Kafka to use it as a distributed database [1].

Though, I'm a bit suspicious about what to expect of that in terms of performance and scalability, especially when compared to Cassandra, as well as unknown pitfalls.

What are the tradeoffs when using Kafka as a distributed DB, and what would it compare performance-wise to "native" distributed systems like Cassandra?

[1] https://www.confluent.io/de-de/blog/pull-queries-in-preview-confluent-cloud-ksqdb/

Comment: The answer lies in the types of queries you actually want to run. Are they KV-lookups, or ranges? Will they include scans of many columns with differing types?

Comment: Indeed that info is missing. Sorry. It will be pure KV lookups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> pure KV lookups

Then Kafka StateStores / Interactive Queries *can* work, **but** with the caveat that if you use containers and an orchestrator, you need to maintain the state of those stores somewhere on persistent volumes. Otherwise, when the containers move to a fresh host, the streams changelog topic needs to be read from the very beginning, giving you a "cold-start" problem, and you will be unable to query.

Using any database (with persistent storage) will not have this problem, and will always be able to query immediately.

I'm not sure I would suggest Cassandra for strictly KV data, though.

Comment: Thanks for that input, I‘ll investigate that problem further. What other database would you suggest?

Comment: Couchbase is well-designed as a distributed cache, in my opinion. Otherwise, Druid or Apache Pinot also have Kafka ingestion facilities built-in and are adopted by Netflix/Uber/LinkedIn data teams